# How can I best display this nested collection? (Can you tell me why my code isn't working?)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemscontrol

Can you tell me why this code isn't working?

I have a viewmodel with an observablecollection of searchresults which has an observablecollection of resultproperties. I cannot seem to display the nested collection of result properties like I want.

Here are the objects (abstracted for readability):

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SearchResults<TDomain>> SearchResults { get; set; }
}

class SearchResults<TDomain>
{
    public TDomain Result { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ResultProperty> ResultProperties { get; set; }
}

class ResultProperty
{
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the xaml I cannot get to work. The DataContext is set to the ViewModel:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding SearchResults}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text={Binding Result.Id}/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding ResultProperties}>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyValue}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <TextBlock Text="PLACEHOLDER /////"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The outcome I am looking for is something like this:

```
[Stack panel to keep things orderly]
1
property1property2property3...
2
property1property2property3...
3
property1property2property3...
PLACEHOLDER /////
```

The results I am getting are these

```
[Stack panel to keep things orderly]
1

2

3

PLACEHOLDER /////
```

In otherwords, the binding isn't picking up the string. I have verified that the collections are populating like expected. But I can't get the xaml to work.

**ADDITION INFORMATION

Ok, so I tried some of the solutions, but they aren't working so I am going to add more details because maybe I am missing something about how the collections are getting updated.

The viewmodel has a button on it called "Search" which uses an ICommand that calls a the view model's TrySearch method which is below:

```
public void TrySearch()
{
    var results = _model.GetAll();
    foreach(var result in results)
        this.SearchResults.Add(new SearchResults<TDomain>(result));
}
```

Could there be a reason this doesn't work because of the way the collection is updated? SearchResults is a dependency property (I know I know, it should be INPC, but its not, its dependency), but the other collections are not. Could this be a problem?

Comment: I copied your code almost exactly (I had remove the generic stuff and generate my own data) and it works!

Comment: None of the solutions so far have worked. I wonder if the generic is causing the problem? But I need the generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that my SearchResults class was not hooked up properly. I made it a dependency object with dependency properties and it works fine. I am assuming that would translate similarly if it was INotifyPropertyChanged. Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

I would create the data templates as resources and refer to them elsewhere in the XAML.  For example:

```
<Window ....>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SearchResultTemplate" TargetType="SearchResults">
            <TextBlock Text={Binding PropertyValue}"
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ViewModelTemplate" TartgetType="ViewModel">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text={Binding Result.Id}/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding ResultProperties} ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchResultTemplate}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding SearchResults} ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ViewModelTemplate}" />
</Window>
```

I'm not sure, but I think that the bindings you're using are telling the XAML parser to look for properties of the ViewModel class called `ResultProperties` and `PropertyValue`.  The XAML parser doesn't see that they're properties of the object bound to that instance of the collection.  Splitting it up like this should make it plain that the properties belong to the instance that the template is being applied to.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't break anything, but I got the same result as before.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is somehow correct but according to what you want it has a flow. The StackPanel has to be the ItemsPanel. Change it like this:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Result.Id}"/>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ResultProperties}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyValue}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBlock Text="PLACEHOLDER /////"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: This yielded for me the same result. I'm going to update my original post and try to add some more details that may be important.